# nodejs: installing stable (0.12.7) with nvm fails

Tags: node.js, nvm

```
$ nvm install stable
######################################################################## 100.0%
mv: cannot move ‘/home/me/.nvm/bin/node-v0.12.7-linux-x64’ to ‘/home/me/.nvm/versions/v0.12.7’: No such file or directory
Binary download failed, trying source.
######################################################################## 100.0%
  File "./configure", line 362
    '''
      ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
nvm: install v0.12.7 failed!
```

This is on a manjaro linux box, running nvm version 0.20.0.

I tried directly with 
`nvm install v0.12.7` or
`nvm install 0.12.7` and also
`nvm install 0.12.6`

all reported the same error.

I also tried re-running the nvm installation script, but it told me it already had nvm installed. I am a bit reluctant to delete .nvm and re-install it (for no obvious reason ;) )

Comment: Does /home/me/.nvm/versions exist?  Does the source /home/me/.nvm/bin/node-v0.12.7-linux-x64 exist?

Comment: @chsh nope. `/home/me/.nvm/bin` is empty

Comment: I found it at `/home/me/.nvm/src/node-v0.12.7.tar.gz`

Comment: What is the OS fo the system? Linux/Windows/Mac ?

Comment: @Kasmetski as mentioned in the question, it's manjaro linux. Updated yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what causes the first problem:

```
mv: cannot move ‘/home/me/.nvm/bin/node-v0.12.7-linux-x64’ to ‘/home/me/.nvm/versions/v0.12.7’: No such file or directory
Binary download failed, trying source.
```

But then it tries from source and tries to compile, using python. The error :

```
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

is from python - python3. By temporarily changin the symlink in manjaro from 
`/usr/bin/python -> python3` to
`/usr/bin/python -> python2`

I seam to have "solved" the issue....

Comment: Still no idea why it doesn't want or can't install the binary